# Cannot put data-te-select-icon={{ asset('vendor/blade-flags/country-vi.svg') }} in collective select form using tailwind

Tags: php, laravel, tailwind-css, laravelcollective, tailwind-elements

I can put select with icon in this code

```
{{ Form::select('country_id', array_column($countries->toarray(), 'name', 'id'), null, ['id'=>'country_id','data-te-select-placeholder'=> old('country_id') ? false :  __('messages_admin.country'),], [1 => ['data-te-select-icon="https://tecdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-4.webp"']]) }}
```

but I cannot put an image in my project like

```
{{ Form::select('country_id', array_column($countries->toarray(), 'name', 'id'), null, ['id'=>'country_id','data-te-select-placeholder'=> old('country_id') ? false :  __('messages_admin.country'),], [1 => ['data-te-select-icon={{ asset('vendor/blade-flags/country-vi.svg') }}']]) }}
```

the error I got:

> syntax error, unexpected identifier "vendor", expecting "]"

Update:
I tried and it worked

```
[1 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-us.svg"]]
```

because the input just sets the image for the first option and if I wanna set for all option I must do this

```
[
  1 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-us.svg"], 
  2 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-us.svg"], 
  3 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-us.svg"], 
...
]
```

Is there any way to do a foreach like the code behind

```
[
<?php
foreach ($countries as $key => $country)echo ($key+1) . ' => ["data- te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"]' . ',';
?>
]
```

I tried but it just print the text:

```
{{ Form::select('country_id', array_column($countries->toarray(), 'name', 'id'), null, ['id'=>'country_id', 'data-te-class-select-option-icon' => 'w-7 h-7 rounded', 'data-te-select-placeholder'=> old('country_id') ? false : __('messages_admin.country'),'class' => 'peer block min-h-[auto] w-full rounded border-0 bg-transparent px-3 py-[0.32rem] leading-[1.6] outline-none transition-all duration-200 ease-linear focus:placeholder:opacity-100 peer-focus:text-primary data-[te-input-state-active]:placeholder:opacity-100 motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-black dark:placeholder:text-black dark:peer-focus:text-primary [&:not([data-te-input-placeholder-active])]:placeholder:opacity-0', 'data-te-select-init', 'data-te-select-filter="true"','data-te-class-select-input="peer block min-h-[auto] w-full rounded border-0 bg-transparent outline-none transition-all duration-200 ease-linear focus:placeholder:opacity-100 data-[te-input-state-active]:placeholder:opacity-100 motion-reduce:transition-none dark:text-black dark:placeholder:text-gray-200 [&:not([data-te-input-placeholder-active])]:placeholder:opacity-0 cursor-pointer data-[te-input-disabled]:bg-[#e9ecef] data-[te-input-disabled]:cursor-default group-data-[te-was-validated]/validation:mb-4 dark:data-[te-input-disabled]:bg-zinc-600"'], [ 
1 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
2 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
3 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
4 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
5 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
6 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
7 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
8 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
9 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
10 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
11 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
12 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
13 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
14 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
15 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
16 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
17 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
18 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
19 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
20 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
21 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
22 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
23 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"],
...
```

Update: I also tried and put the $options into "[]" but not thing appear

```
@php$options = [];foreach ($countries as $key => $country)$options[] = ($key+1) . ' => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-vn.svg"]' . ',';
$options = implode($options);
@endphp
```

Please help me fix this, many thanks !

Comment: `'data-te-select-icon...` is starting with single quotes that get ended in `{{ asset('...`. Use regular quotes in `asset('vendor/blade-flags/country-vi.svg')`. Not really related to Tailwind

Comment: I try [1 => ["data-te-select-icon=/public/vendor/blade-flags/country-us.svg"]] and it works, but it is just the first option, the first option starts with 1, is there any way to use foreach for all options, thanks !

Comment: and I try to push a php variable into it but it didn't work.

Comment: "_it didn't work_" is not a problem description and doesn't help anyone. Please _always_ post complete error messages. Also, please [edit] your question and append the updated code, so everybody knows what you're working with.